# Eloquent models comparation troubles

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, activerecord, eloquent

I have some difficulties with eloquent models in use-case like that:

```
$skill1 = new Skill();
$skill1->title = "Test";
$skill1->save();

$skill3 = Skill::findOrFail($skill1->id);

$this->assertEquals($skill1, $skill3);
```

Asserting gives error, because objects are not equals
[Comparasion result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UTCd.png)
In case we getting object from relation there are lots of new fields (e.g. original->relation)

I know, that there is "is" method in Eloquent models and it works right, but if I need to use core PHP function like in_array (for example, it is using in Collection's "contains" method), comparasion will not work.

The question is "How to compare these two models and use it like that:"

```
$this->assertTrue(collect([$skill1])->contains($skill3));
```

Maybe I can overload compare operator, maybe I can make smthng like IComparable in C#?

Thanks.

Comment: With  `$this->assertEquals()` you can chek only single value.
Please try `$this->assertSame()`

Comment: When are two models equal? When all of their attributes match? Or just the ids?

Comment: In my mind models are equal, when all attributes match.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the attributes, not the whole models:

```
$this->assertEquals($skill1->getAttributes(), $skill3->getAttributes());
```

If you compare a newly created model with a model from the database, `$wasRecentlyCreated` is different (among other things).

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answer?

Comment: Sorry, but it is not completely what i need. Main goal is not passing test, but having semantical use of collection's methods. 
I think the only way to do that is rewrite these methods using "is" method of model